# Apache2 access restricted to local LAN

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Until recently, I had a bunch of virtual sites set up like so:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:1234>
    ...
```

This works fine for testing on my local machine, where I use a Linux desktop.  In order to test how MS and explorer displays my pages from my Windows laptop, I changed this to

```
<VirtualHost *:1234>
    ...
```

Which also works fine, calling the site up from http://[mylinuxservername]:1234 on my laptop's IE.  However, I want to restrict that wildcard to the local lan.  Plugging in any ip, like 192.nnn.nnn.nnn or 192.*.*.* where the wildcard is above results in 403 Forbidden on the windows machine.  The local server still works fine on my Linux box:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:1234 192.*.*.*:1234>
    ...
```

or

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:1234 192.nnn.nnn.nnn:1234> #exact IP of laptop
    ...
```

Anyway, I don't like that wildcard in the second config example above.  Hints anyone?

Comment: This should probably be on ServerFault - though IIRC, your issue is that you don't put the requesting IP in the VirtualHost tag - it goes in a Location or Directory piece.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The parameter(s) of `VirtualHost` are the local addresses you listen to, not the remote ones.

In Apache 2.4 and newer, use the [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive:

```
Require ip 127.0.0.0/8
Require ip 192.0.0.0/8
```

If you are using Apache 2.2 or earlier, use the [authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) configuration:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
```

This may also work on Apache 2.4, but [`Order` and `Allow` have been deprecated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html).

Comment: Thank you!  Works great.  What do the numbers at the end of the ip after the forward slashes mean?

Comment: Jack, The /8 and /16 are lengths of the subnet mask. It's [CIDR Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation)

Comment: So much arcana, so little time :-) Thanks!

Comment: @~jack-laplante Already answered by Ted: CIDR notation (The number of invariable bits)

Comment: this has been deprecated in favor of 'require'. Please, downvote this one and upvote apachenoob's answer

Comment: Updated with a solution for Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note in case some noobs like me come here :)

> Apache HTTP Server is configured by placing directives in plain text
>   configuration files. The main configuration file is usually called
>   httpd.conf.
>   [Main Configuration Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html)

### For version 2.4

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat,
>   are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid
>   using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.
>   [Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html)

```
Require ip 127.0.0.0/8
Require ip 192.0.0.0/8
```

**or** (not exactly the same)

```
Require ip 127.0
Require ip 192.168
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iptables to restrict access to the machine itself. The first command will allow HTTP traffic from any network in the 192 range (note that I think you need 192.168 to truly be local but I could wrong). The second command simply drops packets from other sources for port 80

```
iptables -I 1 INPUT -s 192.0.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


iptables -I 2 INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Then in your virtual host you can do `<VirtualHost *:80>`